# Redirect to the Individual Tabs in css Tab container from Menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, tabs

I have a tab container which contains two tabs like signIn and signUp in a Registration.aspx.As same as I have a menu in Master Form named like sign in and Register.
I have set a SignIn Tab is active when i Click SignIn Menu. as same as I have to set Sign up Tab is active when i click Registration menu. The both SignIn Menu and Registration menu  Redirect to the Same Page which is Registration .aspx

Here is my Code  for css Tab Container

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#login" data-toggle="tab" class="br-lblue"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Sign In</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#register" data-toggle="tab" class="br-lblue"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Sign Up</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content" >
    <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="login">
        <p>
            Paragraph 1
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="register">
        <!-- Register form -->
        <div class="alert alert-info">
            <strong>Register FREE!</strong>
        </div>
        <p>
            Paragraph 2
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do i achieve that?
 Thanks

Comment: @King_Fisher try to use the tab control in ASP.NET and set the tabindex according to what you want using url parameter.

Comment: @FrebinFrancis Is there anyway to do this without Ajax Tab Container?

Comment: ofcourse you can do the same thing using Ajax tab control. What you need to do is set a url parameter in url specifying which tab you want to open and in the page load set the Enabled tab in Tab control http://www.ajaxtutorials.com/asp-net/ajax-control-toolkit-tabscontainer-extender-tutorial-in-asp-net-c/

Comment: You can also use the ActiveTabIndex  property to set the opened Tab.

Comment: @FrebinFrancis Actually i  did this way about 5 forms .If i want to change that in to Ajax then its gonna be a big work for me.Thats why I am looking for solution in a same way what i did. So is it Possible?

Comment: which language are you using ?

Comment: @FrebinFrancis Webforms ,vs2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I did it.Thank God.I used Query String .
I have removed Active css in Tab Container .I added it Dynamically by using Jquery and it  works.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {


        var name = GetParameterValues('SearchType');
        if (name == 'Basic') {
            $('#c-one').addClass("active in");
            $('#c-two').removeClass("active in");

        }
        else if (name == 'Advance') {
        $('#c-two').addClass("active in");
        $('#c-one').removeClass("active in");

    }
    function GetParameterValues(param) {
        var url = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {
            var urlparam = url[i].split('=');
            if (urlparam[0] == param) {
                return urlparam[1];
            }
        }
    }   

    });
```